# Java - Naming variables with language conflicts

Tags: java, naming-conventions, standards

In the Java world, is there any standard or convention for naming variables that have conflicts with the language itself? For example, a variable/parameter of type **Class** can't be named *class*.

I've seen *clazz* used, but in my opinion that is a bit obnoxious; however, if that is the norm I can join that bandwagon.

C# has the ability to prefix an *@* in front of a variable so *@class* is valid, but to my knowledge Java has no such equivalent.

Comment: I don't know if there's a standard. I just won't use reserved words as a variable name.

Comment: If your variable has a meaningful name, its name is unlikely to clash with a keyword. There's no standard, so this is a question of preference.

Comment: Look for a synonym.  For example, in the context of a school use "course" or "lecture" instead of "clazz".

Comment: As suggested by Ernest, I recommand you to use meaningful names, so it can't be a reserved word. For exemple if your class object is local to a function where you check the class name, instead of naming the Class parameter `class` (which is forbidden) use `classToBeChecked` : This is more explicit what this parameter will do, and you won't face naming problem